# Is there any limit for number of events can be added to O365 user calendar using Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to add multiple events to user calendar from Graph API. Is there any limit for number events can be added to O365 user calendar using Graph API or O365 limitation on the user calendar?

Comment: Are you facing any throttling issues like 429 error code?

Comment: I have not handled 429 error in the code but I have faced an issue which says Too Many Retries. I just wanted to know how many events can we add to user calendar graph api or any means? is there limitation on the events for a user calendar?

Comment: and how to handle 429 error from c# Graph client api?

Comment: I don't think that the issue(Too many retries) is with the limit but its the issue with the email address of the attendees in the payload which may not be right. Please check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160962/hubspot3-client-and-too-many-retries-error). And for the 429 error you can go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling) and the video and implement it with graph client accordingly.